# How Store the array of data using ng-storage?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-storage

I made the plunker. i am pushing the item when click on the button and button color will change to red and splice the item in array when click on the same button the color of button will change to the green.

`http://plnkr.co/edit/b6vRVpUKkhPANNVXkkJL?p=preview

My Problem is How to make this functionality with the ng-storage. when i refresh the page pushed items will be constant. and color will be constant.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.tablelist = [{"tablename":"t1"},{"tablename":"t2"}]
$scope.tableArray=[]
$scope.tableslist=[]
$scope.tableget=function(table){
     table.btnClass = table.btnClass == "btn-danger" ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger"
     var exists=false;
     angular.forEach($scope.tableArray, function (list,$index) {
        if ((list.tablename == table.tablename)) {
            console.log(list.tablename)
             console.log(table.tablename)
            exists=true;
            $scope.tableArray.splice($index,1)
            return false
        }
     });
    if(!exists){
    $scope.tableslist.push(table)
  $scope.tableArray=$scope.tableslist
  console.log($scope.tableArray)
   table.color="red"
    }
} 
 });
```

please help me how to do this